# Pure inductor with AC source

Tags: electric-circuits

If we construct a pure inductive circuit with ac source. EMF leads current by 90 phase constant.  According to graph at t=0  EMF increases in positive direction but current decreases in negative direction. EMF is in positive direction but current in opposite direction how it is possible ?

Comment: Is the source a voltage or current source? Is its waveform given as a sine or cosine? Can you share the graph you are referring to?

Comment: In my opinion, you need to understand, in terms of the laws of electromagnetic induction, why $\mathscr E=-L\frac{dI}{dt}$.

Comment: In addition to the graph that you are referring to, you should also share the circuit diagram that you are referring to, with the voltage and current clearly labeled.